# CNTK Distributed Crash - Beta 7

Tags: python, cntk

I am running a variation of the CIFAR 10 distributed to utilize my data.

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CNTK_Train.py", line 158, in <module>
    checkpoint_path = "C:/projects/RoboLabs/CognitiveServices/ML_Models/DocSuite/Doc_Classify/checkpoints/CNTK_VGG9")
  File "CNTK_Train.py", line 80, in train_and_evaluate
    trainer.save_checkpoint(os.path.join(checkpoint_path + "_{}.dnn".format(current_epoch)))
  File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py34\lib\site-packages\cntk\trainer.py", line 138, in save_checkpoint
    super(Trainer, self).save_checkpoint(filename, _py_dict_to_cntk_dict(external_state))
  File "C:\local\Anaconda3-4.1.1-Windows-x86_64\envs\cntk-py34\lib\site-packages\cntk\cntk_py.py", line 1774, in save_checkpoint
    return _cntk_py.Trainer_save_checkpoint(self, *args)
RuntimeError: Runtime exception
```

The code I am using for the training loop with checkpoints is here:

```
while updated:
    data=train_reader.next_minibatch(minibatch_size, input_map=input_map) # fetch minibatch.
    updated=trainer.train_minibatch(data)                                 # update model with it
    progress_printer.update_with_trainer(trainer, with_metric=True)       # log progress
    epoch_index = int(trainer.total_number_of_samples_seen/epoch_size)
    if current_epoch != epoch_index:                                      # new epoch reached
        progress_printer.epoch_summary(with_metric=True)
        current_epoch=epoch_index            
    if current_epoch % 25 == 0:
        trainer.save_checkpoint(os.path.join(checkpoint_path + "_{}.dnn".format(current_epoch)))
```

Insights welcome.  I am actively debugging.

Comment: I think I should put the current_epoch % 25 if statement inside the current_epoch != epoch_index  I'm testing, but its going to take a while for test to complete.  If thats the answer, its a bit of a random type bug to encounter I beleive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be resolved in the latest version which performs check pointing in a different manner.  Solution is to upgrade your CNTK version.  Use the session apis which begin in version 9.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are running in windows environment path format specified in Linux-style. On windows the path should be something like 'X:\Repos\CNTK\Examples\Image\Classification\ResNet\Python\Models\resnet20_0.dnn'. Suggest that you try os.path.join instead of hardcode / or \ in the path string passed to save_model.